# how to encrypt tls 1.0 record layer application data?

Tags: encryption, tls1.0

I am using TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA cipher suite, and I have sucessfully finished the handshake process, so i should have the correct KEYS for the server side and client side, but when i use the server write key and iv to encrypt the data and put under record layer(applicaiton type) send to client, but when i use wireshark ssl debug, i found out that wireshark didn't decrypt the application data correctly, wonder is the application data use a different key to do the encryption and decryption? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like it's really a wireshark question.

Comment: hm... i think might be applicaiton data use a diferent key to encrypt the data? i tried to use wireshark to capture other ssl data, works good. by the way, i use the same keys generate during the handshake process. am i wrong on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem, TLS 1.0 used the last block of encrypted data as new IV to encrypt the data. its a little surprised, the encrypted data is visible on the network, so anyone capture that data can find out the IV.

Comment: The IV is not supposed to be secret.